# Ambiguous use of subscript swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I get an error right before `["toPosition"]` saying Ambiguous use of subscript

```
guard let toLoc = self.currentDetailObj!["toPosition"][0] as? PFGeoPoint else {
            return
}
```

In a previous statement this works fine

```
    guard let fromLoc = self.currentDetailObj!["fromPosition"] as? PFGeoPoint else{
        return
    }
```

Why does the first statement not work? I need the position at index 0.

Comment: Why don't you use `.first`

Comment: after the ["fromPosition"]?

Comment: @matt thanks for the constructive and useful comment dude!

Comment: i can use .firstItem there is now .first thanks @LeoDabus

Comment: @kareem you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use .first

```
guard let toLoc = self.currentDetailObj?["toPosition"].first as? PFGeoPoint else {
            return
}
```